# caret package: how to extract the test data metrics

Tags: r, boxplot, r-caret

I have a dataset that is publicly available ("banknote_authentication").  It has four predictor variables (variance, skewness, entropy and kurtosis) and one target variable (class).  The dataset contains 1372 records.  I am using R version 3.3.2 and RStudio on a Windows machine.

I'm using the caret package to create a cross-validation approach for the following models: logistic regression, LDA, QDA, KNN with k=1,2,5,10,20,50,100.  I need to obtain the test error as well as sensitivity and specificity for each of these methods and present the results in the form of boxplots, compare test error/sensitivity/specificity across these methods.  Here is an example of my logistic regression code:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, savePredictions = TRUE)

mod_fit <- train(class_label~variance+skewness+kurtosis+entropy,  data=SBank, method="glm",  family="binomial", trControl = ctrl, tuneLength = 5)

pred = predict(mod_fit, newdata=SBank)
```

And here is how I am evaluating my models:

```
confusionMatrix(data=pred, SBank$class_label)
```

How do I extract the accuracy, sensitivity and specificity metrics from the test dataset so that I can create the boxplots?  I do not need the summary metrics that are output from the confusion matrix, I need a dataset of these metrics that I can represent graphically.

Comment: A bit of advice on how to ask a question. You have simple question "how to get accuracy, specificity and sensitivity out of a model". Most of the rest of your text is just unneeded noise that offers zero information to us. Moreover, you do not provide a toy example to work on, which means we need to create our own in order to answer your question. All the above will put off many users (including myselft) to provide an answer to a relatively easy question.

Comment: `?confusionMatrix` says it returns a named list. Use the `$` operator or the `[[` to subset different elements